# Selenium Webdriver failing to find element while trying to upload file

Tags: python, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload a file on a webpage using Selenium web driver. I'm trying to just send keys to an `input type='file'` element but the script keeps erring out with the following:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='file']"}
```

Attached is a snapshot of the html page.  I can Xpath right up to the Form element but anything below that fails to be found.  I've tried this with a couple browsers and have increase the wait time for the page to load.  Still same error.  There is a frame reference lower in the html code that I"ve tried to switch to as well but no luck there either.  I'm wondering if the fact that the line below the form line is a `.js` for a drop down is somehow obscuring things? Or that the element is hidden and I can't get to it.

I need to get the input `type='file'` line several lines below the form line.  I've read quite a few of the posts on similar issues here and most seem to point to increasing time which I've already done. I'm not sure how to find out what parent element is causing the hidden attribute or how to make it visible so I can send keys to the file element. Any help is appreciated.

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuaC2.png)

Comment: check if there is any frame present on your page ... if it is then you need to switch it over first

Comment: There is one frame and I switched to it and no luck.  All the elements in the form I cannot reach via xpath.  I am wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the form?

Comment: @shubham Jain I think I am getting closer to my answer.  The elements I need I think are `innerHTML` of the form itself.  My guess is that I have to execute a java script to access the `input type="file"` element I need.  I'm not sure how to find the exact script to do that though?